# INSERT INTO: is there a shorthand to insert duplicate values?

Tags: sql, sql-insert, shorthand

I have a following INSERT query and I am wondering whether it's possible to combine two columns with the same value?
Yes, I must use exactly two of them for future altering.

```
insert into `products`
set
`name` = 'y',
`time` = 'x',
`time2` = 'x';
```

Thinking logically, pseudo-code `time, time2 = 'x'` should work somehow, but it doesn't.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you are using is not the standard syntax for `insert`.  I believe it is special syntax for MySQL.

Here is one way to do this:

```
insert into `products`(name, time, time2)
    select 'y', 'x', 'x';
```

If you are doing this in MySQL and typing this out, you could do something like:

```
insert into `products`(name, time, time2)
    select 'y', val, val
    from (select 'x' as val) t;
```

Of course, in this case, that doesn't save any typing.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that way, but never really prominented that, now I am aware, thank you. Also it's glad that you provided a solution, but probably I will stick to old format.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to specify a value separately for each column.

The only suggestion I can offer for your case is to write a trigger to copy the value of the  `time` column to `time2`. But it's probably not worth it to write a trigger for such a case unless you do it very frequently.

Comment: No means no, thank you; and probably no, I am cycling this just a couple times so it isn't worh it.